# Parse all files in a directory to database doing nothing

Tags: php, mysql

I have a scheduled task that uses wget to download xml updates from an API to a directory.

If I manually run this in MySQL Workbench, it parses the xml file to the database properly:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\WGET\\GetGame.php@id=773'
REPLACE
INTO TABLE test.games (id, GameTitle, Platform, ReleaseDate, Developer, PlatformId);
```

I'm trying to automate this process, as the directory will constantly receive new files to be parsed. I've created a .php script that should check the folder for files and run the SQL query on anything in the folder. (The folder cleans itself out on the hour.)

Running this seems to do nothing. I can confirm that it's logging into the DB, it just seems to stop at the mysql query. (PHP is not my thing, yet, so the issue will probably be a silly syntax error.)

```
<?php 
mysql_connect('localhost','root',''); 
mysql_select_db('test'); 
$files = glob('GetGame.*'); 
foreach($files as $file){ 
   mysql_query("LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '".$file."' REPLACE INTO TABLE test.games (id, GameTitle, Platform, ReleaseDate, Developer, PlatformId);"); 
}
?>
```

Any leads as to what I'm doing wrong will be greatly appreciated. I've found nothing solid online and have tried many variations. I will continue to figure this out and will update this post if I happen to run into it on my own.

Thanks!

Comment: Missing a single quote after `'".$file."`? Easier to spot that sort of thing when using string interpolation, sometimes.

Comment: Woops! That error isn't in the actual php file. Must have deleted it while formatting my post.

Comment: And what does `mysql_error()` say? Are you also passing double-escaped and full paths?

Comment: Sorry Prix. Mario - mysql_error() returns no errors at all. As for full vs double escaped, hadn't thought of it. Will look into that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the attempts, but I've found the solution. My first mistake was assuming $file would return the full path when it actually returns the filename. I created a second variable holding the path to the file, and concatenated the two into a new variable to be used in the mySQL query. Probably not perfect, but it worked in my situation.

```
<?php 
mysql_connect('localhost','root','password') or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db('your_database'); 
$files = glob('filename.ext'); 
foreach($files as $file)
{ 
$path = 'C:\\\\directory\\\\directory\\\\';
$fullpath = $path . $file;
echo $fullpath;
mysql_query("LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '".$fullpath."' REPLACE INTO TABLE database.table (columns, to, parse, into, database)") 
  or die("A MySQL error has occurred. Error: (" . mysql_errno() . ") " .mysql_error()); 

    }
  echo "Rows affected: " . mysql_affected_rows();
  mysql_close();
?>
```

I'm posting the full script because I've yet to see a good simple solution to this. When googling "parse folder xml to mysql" This post is the second result, so hopefully this will help some people out.

What this will do: As long as you change the $path variable to the folder holding your XML file with 4 backslashes instead of one, it will pass the full path to mySQL in a format that it accepts. The script prints each file processed and prints the number of effected rows after running. If there is a mySQL error, it prints the error.